# Is it possible to solve this first order differential equation analytically?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the equations for the path of a projectile moving under constant gravity and affected by air resistance and I come up against this nasty FODE.

Is there a means by which it could be solved analytically for $y(x)$ or $x(y)$?

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} + \operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)=K-\frac{a}{x^{2}},$$

where $K$ and $a$ are real, positive constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Air drag projectile motion is only solvable if air drag is treated as linear. Anything higher than that is not analytically solvable.